# BadMethodCallException Method App\Http\Controllers\TaskController::destory does not exist

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using laravel 5.8 and this is my routes/api.php file.

```
Route::get('/tasks', 'TaskController@index')->name('tasks.index');
Route::post('/tasks', 'TaskController@store')->name('tasks.store');
Route::get('/tasks/{task}', 'TaskController@show')->name('tasks.show');
Route::put('/tasks/{task}', 'TaskController@update')->name('tasks.update');
Route::delete('/tasks/{task}', 'TaskController@destory')->name('tasks.destroy');
```

And this is function destroy() inside TaskController,

```
public function destroy(Task $task)
{
    $task->delete();

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Successfully deleted task!'
    ]);
}
```

But when I call the function I get this error,

> BadMethodCallException Method
> App\Http\Controllers\TaskController::destory does not exist.

Comment: Your message refers to `destory` your code shows a method `destroy`. Note that the "o" and the "r" are in different orders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it's not the typo.

You are basically calling a function **`destory`** but your controller function name is **`destroy`**
Should be fixed by making it the same.

```
Route::delete('/tasks/{task}', 'TaskController@destroy')->name('tasks.destroy');
```

Comment: This should be a comment to clarify, followed by a vote to close - not an answer